# Taking json from one website to display on html website

Tags: html, json

Im trying to take the json outputted from a specific website, and display that info on my html website. For example, this would be the json on the site example.com,

```
[ { "nickname":"name", "votes":"3"  },  { "nickname":"name", "votes":"2"    },  { "nickname":"name", "votes":"2"    }]
```

How could i get the data from example.com and display it on my html website mydomain.com? Any help would be amazing!

Comment: you can use ajax with jQuery..  Check a look here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just parse it as json object the run a loop to display it anyway you like, run the below example I made.

```js
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);

for (i = 0; i < obj.employees.length; i++) { 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=
obj.employees[i].firstName + " " + obj.employees[i].lastName+ "<br/>";    
}
```

```html
<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! How would i go about grabbing the data from the website instead of having it already there in var text?

Comment: that depends what server side tech ur using, whatever server side tech ur using u need to initiate a http get or post according to ur needs.

Comment: $.getJSON('example.com', function(result) {});
If i used this, result is the json string right? Could i parse that directly?